# How to protect data after unlocking bootloader?

Tags: security

I am to root my Nexus, so I have to unlock it first. But I worry that once done, some one may boot with customized recovery to copy or modify my files. Any idea?

Comment: there is nothing that can be done to address this concern, just as there can be no gaurentee that an adversary with physical access to the device can unlock it themselves to do the same. The Nexus root toolkit has a "relock" feature, that makes android believe its on a locked partition, but in reality, once unlocked, the device cannot be locked again, so don't count on the little open-padlock icon to tell you if someone who had your device didn't root it done their business, and then relocked the device.

Comment: @FrankThomas I may misunderstand your words, I feel sorry if I do. Unlocking an unrooted devices require data swiping, how can my adversary unlock my device, access my files and then relock my device? Without unlocking and third-party recovery, I know no way to access files. What I worry is that once I unlock my Nexus, someone can access my files while I don't know what's happened.

Comment: @Noverull - Which is the point Frank made.  Once unlocked the partition cannot actually be locked again, it says its locked, but its actually unlocked.  `Its sort of like a paper padlock on the door.`

Comment: @Noverull, you are correct, there will be dataloss immediately after unlocking, but the stock recovery system allows the attacker sufficient ability to back up your content, that they could restore your old apps and data such that you would not likely notice.

Comment: The main takeaway here is a very old adage *Physical Access == Root Access. Period.*  So, all the above said, since there is nothing you can do about it either way, I'd recommend unlocking your phone if that will give you functionality you want (and you don't mind voiding your warranty). The main point of locking from a data protection standpoint is bad apps. as such, be more concerned about what apps can get superuser, rather than what an adversary with physical access can do.

Comment: @FrankThomas Get it! Thanks. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @FrankThomas Is there any reference to bakuping my content using stock recovery?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, but my point was simply that if an adversary had your locked/stock device for any real period of time, they could backup your content, unlock and root your device, do nefarious things, relock it, and finally restore your content. It would be quite difficult to know anything had been done to it, unless you looked rather carefully. This seems to be the concern you had about unlocking your device in the first place, so it makes little difference as to whether they can copy or modify files on the locked partition.

Comment: @FrankThomas You've explained it very clear. Thanks again for your kindness. I'm now just curious about how it happens to backup content in one phone with stock recovery for I've searching but eventually found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I find an app named [BootUnlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.segv11.bootunlocker) which allow rooted device have bootloader locked/unlocked without swiping data.